# SOLR Spell checker not working well with multiple words

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm using Solr 7.2.1, I'm trying to implement the 'Did you mean' feature, I've configured the spell check handler and it's working well, the issue is when trying with multiple words, if only one word was spelled correctly, no results are returned.
For example if I write '**drive caq**', it returns me empty results, if I write '**caq**' as a single word, it returns me the correctly spelled word which is '**car**'.
I want it t return me correctly spelled collations as '**drive car**'

Solr Configurations:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">title</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.5</float>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="df">title</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.build">true</str> 
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

the code for using the spell check component:

```
  using (IProviderSearchContext ctx = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_sxa_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
                {
                    var results = ctx.GetSpellCheck(new SolrQuery(Term), new SpellCheckHandlerQueryOptions()
                    {
                        SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters()
                        {
                            Count = 10,
                            Build = true,
                            Collate = true
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
```

with

```
<str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
```

in `<searchComponent name="spellcheck">` node of `solrconfig.xml`

rebuild dictionary and request spell checking like:

```
var results = ctx.GetSpellCheck(new SolrQuery(Term), new SpellCheckHandlerQueryOptions()
{
    SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters()
    {
        Count = 10,
        Build = true,
        Collate = true
    }
});

if (results != null && results.SpellChecking != null && results.SpellChecking.Count > 0)
{
    var words = terms.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (words.Length < 2)
    {
        return results.SpellChecking.SelectMany(x => x.Suggestions);
    }

    var correct = "";
    foreach (var w in words)
    {
        var suggest = results.SpellChecking.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Query.Equals(w));
        if (suggest != null && suggest.Suggestions.Any())
        {
            correct += suggest.Suggestions.First() + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            correct += w + " ";
        }
    }
    return new List<string> { correct.Trim() };
}
return new List<string>();
```

**Update**

As you mentioned in comments, `/spell?q=title:term` works only if term is one word. It is not so. When you spell checking by multiple words you can catch error `undefined field _text_` because it is default configuration of `<initParams path="/spell>`. Just relpace `initparams` for spellchecking in `solrconfig.xml` with:

```
  <initParams path="/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">title</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

Your query to Solr will look similar to

```
/spell?q=:word1 word2 word3&start=0&rows=5&fl=title&fq=_indexname:(your_index_name)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=5
```

and it should works fine (it works for me).

[image]

*I also noticed that your use field name `title` without any postfix, it is ok if it is your custom configuration. If not, your should use it with postfix like `title_t` (the same name as you see in solr) in all definitions in `solrconfig.xml`.*

Comment: I tried it, I used WordBreakSolrSpellChecker and rebuilt the dictionary, but no data returned at all, I tried even using the solr '/spell' endpoint, but no results returned also.

Comment: I found the issue, I'm using the Sitecore API, so I looked at its code, the parameter used for adding the query is 'q', it's hardcoded so it'll always be 'q', I tried the '/spell' endpoint at Solr, the 'q' parameter works fine with one word only, for multiple words 'spellcheck.q' should be used, I don't know how to override or change this honestly.

Comment: @MohamedYaseen, I updated my answer, try to define `initparams` for spellchecker.

Comment: yes it worked, thank you so much, it works perfect now.

Comment: I have another issue don't know to post it in another question or not, the 'title' field I use has few values, when I use other field with more than 2k values, no results are returned

Comment: @MohamedYaseen, it should work regardless of the amount of data. Just double check your configuration and log files for errors.